# PHP profile columns visibility + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, visibility

I'm seeking for the best method to implement the column visibility in users profile.

Imagine the following scenario:

```
Name   : stackoverflow   | [checkbox] visible = 1
Address: New York        | [checkbox] visible = 0
Phone  : 312 021 11      | [checkbox] visible = 1
Email  : stack@stack.com | [checkbox] visible = 1
```

With this, I have two tables: profile and profile_visibility

**profile**

```
ID
ID_User (joins with the User table)
Address
Phone
Email
```

**profile_visibility**

```
ID
ID_User (joins with the User table)
Address
Phone
Email
```

The fields of profile_visibility are all (except id_user and id) of **tinyint** data.

Now, I would like to make a loop to all columns to check if that column is visibile or not, instead of making conditions (because I have more than that columns). Something like:

```
$profile = $this->profile($id); // gets the info (as array) of profile
$visibility = $this->profile_visibility($id); // gets the visibility of fields

for($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($profile) - 1; $i++){
   /* I can't match $profile with $visibility because the values are different..

      $profile[$i]['name'] == $visibility[$i]['name']

      $profile[$i]['name'] > it's equal to: 'stackoverflow'
      $visibility[$i]['name'] > it's equal to: '1'

   */
}
```

EDIT: **Solved** -> But it's not the best solution, see @niyou solution.

```
foreach($visibility as $key => $val) {
    if($val == 1){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $profile)){
            $content .= "<tr>
                            <td class='text-align-right'>
                                <b>" . ucfirst($key) . "</b>:
                            </td>
                            <td class='width-100'>" . $profile[$key] . "</td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have the value of $visibility[$i]['name'], which is '1'. Is this value not considered to actually say 'name is visible'? And if the value was '0', would it not be considered to be invisible.

Comment: Actually `$visibility[$i]` is totally wrong..because I receive data from only one user..so there's no sense to make a multidimension array..I've changed that to only `$visibility['name']` and `$profile['name']`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its a matter of your design:

I would create a table `profile_fields` where i define my possible data fields

`profile_fields: field_id,field_name,field_position,...`

My other Table holds the information whether a field ist visible or not for a user - named `user_fields`

`user_fields: user_field_id, user_id, field_id, visible`

Now you can easily query only those fields which are visible for a user:

```
SELECT field_id, field_name
FROM profile_fields
    LEFT JOIN user_fields USING (field_id)
WHERE user_id=$user_id AND visible=true
```

Comment: Actually, your solution is the best pratice. I've manage to get this working by PHP code..but I've to accept your answer as correct.